# Does every monoidal category admit a braiding?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

The question is in the title.

To make the statement more precise, is is true that for any given monoidal category $(\mathcal C, I, \otimes)$ there exists at least one braiding $\beta$? In other words, does the forgetful functor from braided monoidal categories admit a section (not a left adjoint!)?

I strongly suspect the answer to be 'no', or at least 'yes but not functorially'.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, sometimes there are even $x,y$'s with no abstract isomorphism $x\otimes y \cong y\otimes x$.

Here are two families of examples:

- Monoids, viewed as discrete categories. The tensor product is just the multiplication, and the existence of a braiding would simply mean that the monoid is commutative, which it typically isn't.
- Functor categories : if $C$ is a category, then $Fun(C,C)$ is monoidal with respect to $\circ$, but it's quite rare for endofunctors to commute.

Comment: Ha, monoids! What an easy counterxample! Of course!